# Decode the hidden message!

Tags: code-golf, string, cryptography

## Introduction

One day, you were just relaxing in your office in the CIA, when suddenly you see an alert on your computer. Your programs have just intercepted hundreds of coded messages! A quick examination reveals the rule for encoding, but you need a program in order to decode fast.

## Challenge

You will be given a list of strings, separated by commas. Each string will contain either:

- Part of the coded message

  - It is part of the coded message if it is **not** in the form `a=b`. Note that it **is** part of the message if it is `ab=c`. Add this string to the coded message.
- Part of the encoding scheme

  - This will be in the form of `a=b`. That means that all a's in the message must be replaced by b's. Note that it could be `a==`, meaning that all a`s must be replaced with ='s.

Your program must then output the message, decoded using the scheme found.

Other info:
Your input will only contain commas for separating the strings. It could contain other characters, like !1#, etc. It will not contain uppercase letters. Bits of decoding info do not decode each other. Only the message is affected by the decoding information. Only one replacement will be given for each character, e.g. no `"io,"i=u","i=g"`

## Examples

Input:`"ta","y=s","y","a=e","b=t","b"," ","j","j=1"`

Output:`test 1`

Input:`"z=p","zota","g=e","yugkb","y=t","u=o","k=s","li","fg","b=="`

Output:`potatoes=life`

Input:`"p","=","==n","ot","p=a","hiz","i=e","z=r"`

Output:`another`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: oh yeah, sorry! editting

Comment: What about transitivity and circularity, e.g. `"massega","e=a","a=e"` and the like?

Comment: bits of decoding info do not decode each other. Only the message is affected by the decoding information.

Comment: also, only one replacement will be given for each character, e.g. no `"io,"i=u","i=g"`

Comment: Thanks, I suggest adding this information to the specification.

Comment: Can the input be taken as list of strings in the language's native list format? Like `["a","b","b=c"]`.

Comment: @RainerP. yes, it can. as long as decoding will work if "[" is in one of the strings

Comment: Is `a=bc` part of the encoding or part of the message? What about `a=`?

Comment: Can output be a newline separated list of characters?

Comment: @Titus that would be part of the message, since it is not `a=b`

Comment: @math_junkie that would have to be a no.

Comment: Can we assume the message can never be all equals signs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḊṖ⁼“=”
ÇÐfKm2yÇÐḟF$
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wR9fDndMeNe551DDH9lHDXK7D7YcnpHnnGlWCGA93zHdT@f//f7RSgZKOki0I2@YByfwSIFFgmwgkMzKrgGSmbSqQrLItUooFAA)**

#### How?

```
ḊṖ⁼“=” - Link 1, isMappngElement?: string
Ḋ      - dequeue
 Ṗ     - pop
   “=” - char-list,['=']
  ⁼    - equal?

ÇÐfKm2yÇÐḟF$ - Main link: list of strings
 Ðf          - filter keep:
Ç            -     last link (1) as a monad
   K         - join with spaces
    m2       - modulo 2 slice (every other character)
           $ - last two links as a monad:
        Ðḟ   -     filter discard:
       Ç     -         last link (1) as a monad
          F  -     flatten
      y      - translate right according to the mapping of left
```

Comment: Very interesting, what does m2 "modulo 2 slice" mean?

Comment: `m` is a dyadic atom that takes every right-th element of left*. Here, for example, `['x','=','y','<space>','a','=','b']m2` would yield `['x','y','a','b']`. (* unless right is zero when it appends a reflection instead.)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 98

```python
lambda l:''.join(x*('='!=x[1:-1])for x in l).translate({'='!=x[1:-1]or ord(x[0]):x[2:]for x in l})
```

This `lambda` function receives a list of strings (input) and returns a string (the decoded message).

Examples:

```python
>>> f(['ta', 'y=s', 'y', 'a=e', 'b=t', 'b', ' ', 'j', 'j=1'])
'test 1'
>>> f(['z=p', 'zota', 'g=e', 'yugkb', 'y=t', 'u=o', 'k=s', 'li', 'fg', 'b=='])
'potatoes=life'
>>> f(['p', '=', '==n', 'ot', 'p=a', 'hiz', 'i=e', 'z=r'])
'another'
```

Comment: Do you need :-1 or will :2 work?

Comment: @DSM I think it's needed because `'=' == x[1:2]` will be true for `x = 'a=bc'`, which is not a part of the encoding scheme

Comment: Ahh, good point!

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 85 bytes

```
f x=[(a,b)|[a,'=',b]<-x]
h x=map(\v->maybe v id$lookup v$f x)$concat[c|c<-x,[]==f[c]]
```

#### Usage

```
>h ["p","=","==n","ot","p=a","hiz","i=e","z=r"]
>"another"
```

#### Description

`f` creates a lookup table.

`concat[c|c<-x,[]==f[c]]` extracts the message.

`map(\v->maybe v id$lookup v$f x)` perfoms the lookup.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```
(l,s='',d={})=>l.map(v=>/.=./.test(v)?d[v[0]]=v[2]:s+=v)&&[...s].map(c=>d[c]||c).join``
```

```html
<input id=a oninput="try{b.innerText=((l,s='',d={})=>l.map(v=>/.=./.test(v)?d[v[0]]=v[2]:s+=v)&&[...s].map(c=>d[c]||c).join``)(eval(`[${a.value}]`))}catch(e){}"/>
<p id=b />
```

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, <s>84</s> <s>82</s> <s>77</s> 74 bytes

Takes a comma-separated list as input. Note the trailing newline

```
^|$
,,
+`,(.=.)(,.*)
$2$1
M!&`(.).*,,.*\1=.|.+,
%`(.).*,$|.*(.)
$1$2
\n|,
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#LYxBDoIwFET3/xSaFFNg0qTs/9qVNyCGligCBoiWBU3vjl/jZjKZmTeZPjf7NSkCqGygDZtcwxQ5qUpZuhxPjTa5KSBZbdkkU4Kyf6aSKcSRsqqiekqgfQ8OG7@xwfENngM8DhgwsKXIC@Isg06qbe1GL9OAlWeMgjx73DtBmBYwmCfMAQs7PPqIXpDIL3K@leeveP45bj8)

**Explanation:**

First, we move all expressions of the form `.=.` to the end of the string and separate these from the message with a double comma (`,,`). This is so that in the next step, we can find all encodings by checking if each character ahead of the `,,` has a matching `=.` afterwards. This is achieved by `` M!&`(.).*,,.*\1=.|.+, `` which finds all such matches and places them into a linefeed separated list of strings. We then modify each string to only contain either one unencoded character or the encoded version of the character. Finally we replace all linefeeds and commas with the empty string so that our output is formatted nicely.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 188 bytes

```
@echo off
set/pm=
set c=
for %%s in (%m%)do call:c %%s "%%c%%%%~s" not
for %%s in (%m%)do call:c %%s "%%c:%%~s%%"
echo %c%
exit/b
:c
set s=%~1
if %3 "%s:~1,1%"=="=" call set c=%~2
```

Explanation: Loops through the list of strings twice (conveniently `for` likes a string in CSV format). The first time, looks for strings that do not contain an `=` as the second character, and concatenates them to the result. The second time, looks for strings that do contain an `=` as the second character, and performs the substitution. (even more conveniently, the substitution is already in Batch format.)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 116 Bytes

```
<?foreach($_GET as$i)$i[1]=="="&&strlen($i)==3?$r[]=$i:$s.=$i;foreach($r as$l)$s=str_replace($l[0],$l[2],$s);echo$s;
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c45c0d1bcbef3abdd22c0d8823f8a9f7ded3b7f)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <s>89</s> 87 bytes

two versions:

```php
while(a&$s=$argv[++$i])3==strlen($s)&"="==$s[1]?$t[$s[0]]=$s[2]:$m.=$s;echo strtr($m,$t);
while(a&$s=$argv[++$i])preg_match("#^.=.$#",$s)?$t[$s[0]]=$s[2]:$m.=$s;echo strtr($m,$t);
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-nr`.

- loop through arguments creating parameters for `strtr`
  (translation if argument contains `=`, message else).
- perform `strtr`.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 31 bytes

```
vy'=åyg3Q&iyˆyS}})øJÁ¨`¹¯KJ.Ás‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@19WqW57eGllunGgWmbl6bbK4NpazcM7vA43HlqRcGjnofXeXnqHG4sfNSz8/z9aqcq2QElHqSq/JBFIpdumAsnK0vTsJBBtWwIkS23zgWS2bTGQzMkEEmnpQCLJ1lYp9mtevm5yYnJGKgA)

```
vy              }
  '=åyg3Q&                      # See if it's length 3 with an equals in the mid.
          iyˆyS                 # If so, add to global array, split into chars.
               } 
                 )øJÁ¨`         # Transpose, join, and remove the middle =.
                       ¹¯KJ     # Push original input without decryption key.
                           .Ás‡ # Shift stack to the right, swap and transliterate.
```